# R - Find unique minimum across array dimension

Tags: arrays, r, min

In a 4D array, I would like to find the unique minimum value across the 4th dimension. I want to get a matrix of the array indices for the minimum.

I have tried solving the issue with the following code block. I would have liked using `which.min`, but I haven't found a good way to return the array indices.

```
dims =c(3,3,3,4)

# create sample data with multiple mins in [,,,1]
mat_rep = array(c(rep(0,3),sample(1:prod(dims))), dim = dims)
pos_rep = apply(mat_rep, 4, function(x) which(x == min(x), arr.ind = T)) # get position of unique minimum 

# create sample data with unique min
mat_norep = array(sample(1:prod(dims)), dim = dims)
pos_norep = apply(mat_norep, 4, function(x) which(x == min(x), arr.ind = T))

# formating depending on class of pos_ object
format_pos = function(x, dims){
  if(class(x) == "matrix") x = t(x)
  if(class(x) == "list") x = do.call(rbind, lapply(x, head, 1))
  x = cbind(x, 1:dims[4]) # add 4th dimension
  return(x)
}

format_pos(pos_norep, dims = dims)
format_pos(pos_rep, dims = dims)
```

The described solution works, however it doesn't work generally and the `if(class())` and `cbind(x, 1:dims[4])` in my opinion is prone to producing errors. 
Does someone have a cleaner way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create uniform outputs you can call `arrayInd` explicitly on the output of `apply(..., which.min)`, instead of implicitly as in `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)`. The fourth dimension indices still need to be added manually though:

```r
## add 4D indices using 1D values
start.ind <- (seq_len(dims[4]) - 1) * prod(head(dims, 3))

arrayInd(apply(mat_rep, 4, which.min) + start.ind, .dim = dims)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    1
#> [2,]    1    3    3    2
#> [3,]    1    3    2    3
#> [4,]    3    1    1    4
arrayInd(apply(mat_norep, 4, which.min) + start.ind, .dim = dims)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    2    1    3    1
#> [2,]    1    2    1    2
#> [3,]    1    2    1    3
#> [4,]    2    2    3    4

## add 4D indices using cbind
cbind(arrayInd(apply(mat_rep, 4, which.min), .dim = head(dims, 3)), seq_len(dims[4]))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    1
#> [2,]    1    3    3    2
#> [3,]    1    3    2    3
#> [4,]    3    1    1    4

cbind(arrayInd(apply(mat_norep, 4, which.min), .dim = head(dims, 3)), seq_len(dims[4]))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    2    1    3    1
#> [2,]    1    2    1    2
#> [3,]    1    2    1    3
#> [4,]    2    2    3    4
```

**Data**

```r
dims <- c(3,3,3,4)
mat_rep <- array(c(rep(0,3),sample(1:prod(dims))), dim = dims)
mat_norep <- array(sample(1:prod(dims)), dim = dims)
```